# How do I apply the same changes on multiple data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file (named subdatlob) containing a list of data frames (4dfs namely 1,2,3, and 4). For each data frame, I want to implement the following

```
tri_I=as.triangle(subdatlob[["I"]],origin="AY",dev="DY",value="paid")
triLoB_I = incr2cum(tri_I)
```

for I = 1,2,3,4 or more generally, for each data frame I in the given list.

How do I do this? I will also be doing this step for a list containing 1,000,000+ data frames.

This inquiry involves applying a function to every data frame and naming the necessary variables for the computation.

Comment: `lapply(subdatlob, \(x) incr2cumc(as.triangle(x,origin="AY",dev="DY",value="paid")))`

Comment: @shs Thanks, this worked for me. Is this supposed to work given any data frame dimensions?

Comment: I don't know the functions `as.triangle()` and `incr2cumc()`, so I don't know. But `lapply()` does not add any constraints on the elements of the elements of the input list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shs's suggestion

```
lapply(subdatlob, \(x) incr2cumc(as.triangle(x,origin="AY",dev="DY",value="paid")))
```

worked for me and for my larger list containing more data frames.